# predict() function - How to use with mixed independent variables (ln() & level)

Tags: r, regression, prediction, predict

My regression model is like:

```
model <- lm(ln(y) ~ ln(x) + z + ln(t)*z, na.action=na.exclude, data = df )
```

Here I would like to make prediction with `predict()` instead of getting coefficients with `tidy()` and manually making the calculation with `exp()`. How should I construct my predict function to get level base y for my each observation.

Comment: You use `predict` just like with any other model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do so like this:

```
df = data.frame(x=runif(10,1,10),y=runif(10,1,10),t=runif(10,1,10),z=runif(10,1,10))

model <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x) + z + log(t)*z, na.action=na.exclude, data = df )
base_y = predict(model,data=df)
```

Output:

```
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
1.273505 1.563740 1.426931 1.097606 1.462620 1.211534 1.808578 1.749929 1.698873 1.193925
```

Hope this helps!